# Microsoft Exchange Notification Service

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

I'm writing a .NET service to monitor an exchange mailbox. The service needs to download and process any email sent to that mailbox.

I currently have a console app that checks and downloads email. I can then schedule that to run every 5 minutes.

Is this the only solution? Is there a trigger I can set on the Exchange server that can run the console app on the event that a new mail arrives?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a access (and control) of the exchange installation? You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx  - Exchange Web Services (EWS) Managed API to work with mailboxes.

Comment: I am using EWS to create the console app. As far as I know, it doesn't have functionality to trigger on new email while running on the exchange server.

Comment: Then you need to use some sort of Push notification like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204063%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

In other scenarios you may use some Pull (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa579617%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)